# Sqlite Error on Phonegap "near ".": syntax error"

Tags: sqlite, cordova

I'm working on a phonegap application using cordova 1.9. 
I have a syntax error on this statement:

```
db.executeSql('UPDATE Reminder SET Reminder.reminderName ="'+ reminder_name + '", Reminder.reminderDescription = "' + description +'", Reminder.cellId='+ 1 +',  Reminder.timetableId ='+1+', Reminder.reminderDeadline ="' + deadline +'" WHERE Reminder.RminId = "'+reminderId+'" ');
```

SO, I'm wondering what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't know phonegap, but if this is at all standard SQL, then I would swap the single and double quotes.  SQL needs single quotes, no? (Also, someone is bound to comment on the huge SQL injection security hole here, too)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be an issue with your 1's.

where you are entering a 1, you should either put this in a variable or leave the quotes out:

```
db.executeSql('UPDATE Reminder SET Reminder.reminderName ="'+ reminder_name + '", Reminder.reminderDescription = "' + description +'", Reminder.cellId=1,  Reminder.timetableId =1, Reminder.reminderDeadline ="' + deadline +'" WHERE Reminder.RminId = "'+reminderId+'" ');
```

or

```
var cellID = 1;
var timetableID = 1;
db.executeSql('UPDATE Reminder SET Reminder.reminderName ="'+ reminder_name + '", Reminder.reminderDescription = "' + description +'", Reminder.cellId='+ cellID +',  Reminder.timetableId ='+timetableID+', Reminder.reminderDeadline ="' + deadline +'" WHERE Reminder.RminId = "'+reminderId+'" ');
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your single quotes and double quotes wrong and messy.
Try this:

```
    db.executeSql("UPDATE Reminder SET Reminder.reminderName = "
            + reminder_name + ", Reminder.reminderDescription = "
            + description + ", Reminder.cellId = " + 1
            + ",  Reminder.timetableId = " + 1
            + ", Reminder.reminderDeadline = " + deadline
            + " WHERE Reminder.RminId = " + reminderId + " ");
```